# ionic3 using ref attr in span tag html

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have using some javascript in html page in the ionic3 project.

```
<span id="time" ref="{{product.time}}"></span>
```

But when build the project have error below:

```
Can't bind to 'ref' since it isn't a known property of 'span'.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `ref` here? is that custom property?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Sorry finally i use angular way ngmodel to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a *custom attribute*, you could use the `attribute binding` like this:

```
<span id="time" [attr.ref]="product.time"></span>
```